# Erratic behaviour of a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query :

```
 SELECT days.from, days.to, days.nombre, days.totalDays, days.bloque, 
        days.comentario, days.local, admin.eMail, admin.passcode, days.id, 
        admin.username
 FROM days,admin
 WHERE days.id='9' AND days.nombre=admin.username
```

The problem is that the query somethimes work but sometimes doesnt. Sometimes works with only certain IDs. Is there any other way to formulate the query?

Comment: You should look into using a JOIN rather than the way you're doing it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected and current output?

Comment: Join wont work, because you dont have a common column in both tables. eg you need days.id = admin.id something like this for a join to work.

Comment: Sometimes give correct answer and sometimes it doesnt, that how I know that it more strange than normal.

Comment: Join will work. He is using a natural key of `days.nombre` and `admin.username`. Those are still keys and they are common to eachother.

Comment: Echoing smcjones:  @Harry: the OP query already does perform a JOIN operation, albeit, the statement is using old-school comma syntax for the join operator. And true, we'd prefer to see that old-school comma syntax replaced with the newer `JOIN` keyword, and see the join predicate moved from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON clause; but the query already does perform a JOIN operation.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up guys, I haven't come across the old-school way of doing joins. So I went on my current knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using implicit joins. [Explicit joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) are easier to read and understand for you and tend to make for much more consistent queries.

You could rewrite your query using `JOIN`s. So, instead of:

```
SELECT days.from, days.to, days.nombre, days.totalDays, days.bloque, 
       days.comentario , days.local, admin.eMail, admin.passcode, 
       days.id, admin.username 
FROM days,admin  
WHERE days.id='9' 
AND days.nombre=admin.username
```

You can use:

```
SELECT days.from,days.to,days.nombre,days.totalDays,days.bloque,
       days.comentario,days.local,admin.eMail,admin.passcode,
       days.id,admin.username
FROM days
INNER JOIN admin ON days.nombre=admin.username
WHERE days.id='9'
```

You may be able to note already how much easier it is to understand what is happening here. While this shouldn't in and of itself fix your query, it is far easier to read and thus to debug.

If you find that certain cases are not working, the best way to figure out why is to remove some restrictions and see if it then works. In this instance, make sure that the usernames that are not showing up have the column `days.id` equal to 9. Other potential issues when using a natural key are things like extra white space. Check for this in cases that do not work as the `JOIN` property `days.nombre=admin.username` may be failing.

Your other option, if, in fact, whitespaces are causing you issues, is to do away with your natural keys and implement surrogate keys. Surrogate keys mean that you will be using a standard and unique key code like an `int` that increments over time. Rather than have `days.nombre` as your foreign key, you would have `days.admin_id` as your foreign key.

As a rule, while there are many pros to natural keys and it is a debate which rages on, it is generally accepted that natural keys only work if the keys are consistent and unique.

Comment: That was the thing I was thinking as well, that the white spaces are causing problem but there is no way around it. i tried your version, but yes its doing the same thing.

Comment: I have updated to provide another suggestion. If you have or might have whitespace in your keys that cause them to be inconsistent across tables they will quickly cause you nightmares. In this case you probably want to consider a surrogate key.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but here's something that caused a problem for me recently: check your table and column definitions that the character sets are consistent. It looks like you have a mixture of English and Spanish, so perhaps some non-ASCII characters like ñ are not matching as expected.